# TFS C# Update Steps in TestCases

Tags: c#, tfs, testcase

Im trying to update the field steps as with other fields

testCase.Fields["field"].Value = "value";

but is still empty after the change. 
How can I modify the steps in a Test Case?

Answer (score 1):

Test Case is different with normal work items like Bug or Task. You need to use "ITestManagementService" in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client to update test case. Check the code below for reference:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.TestManagement.Client;

namespace TFSDownloadFile
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://tfscollectionurl/";
            TfsTeamProjectCollection ttpc = new TfsTeamProjectCollection(new Uri(url));
            ITestManagementService itms = ttpc.GetService<ITestManagementService>();
            ITestManagementTeamProject itmtp = itms.GetTeamProject("YourProject");
            //Get test case with test case id
            ITestCase itc = itmtp.TestCases.Find(1);
            //Get the first step in test case
            ITestStep teststep = itc.Actions[0] as ITestStep;
            //Update the test step
            teststep.Title = "New Title";
            teststep.ExpectedResult = "New ExpectedResult";
            //Save the updated test case
            itc.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the Actions property. This will return a [TestActionCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.testactioncollection.aspx) that you can use to update the steps. You can use the [ITestStep](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.client.iteststep.aspx) interface for each action in the collection to update the Title, Description, and ExpectedResult for each step. Don't forget to call `Save()` on the workitem.